# javascript / jquery - google custom search api - functions triggering twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-custom-search

I'm using the code from the google search API along with my own jquery function to do a simple log to the console, and I noticed the jquery functions are being triggered twice. In addition, javascript errors are being thrown (this happens even on Google's example page).

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        google.load('search', '1', {language : 'en'});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
            var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('000638822871137547098:_xxgiq7wt_k');
            var linkTarget = "frame";
            //customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
            //customSearchControl.draw('cse');

            // Use "mysite_" as a unique ID to override the default rendering.
            google.search.Csedr.addOverride("mysite_");
            customSearchControl.setLinkTarget(linkTarget)
            // Draw the Custom Search Control in the div named "CSE"
            customSearchControl.draw('cse');

            $('.gsc-search-button').click(function(){
                console.log('click');
            })

            // Execute an initial search
            //customSearchControl.execute("ajax");


        }, true);
    </script>
```

and here's the javascript error that occurs:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL http://www.google.com/cse?q=x&client=google-coop&hl=en&r=s&cx=000638822871137547098%3A_xxgiq7wt_k&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8&format=n4&ad=n0&adsafe=high&nocache=1319551264502&fexp=20606&num=0&safe=off&output=uds_ads_only&source=gcsc&v=3&adext=as1%2Csr1&rurl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2F#slave-1-1. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Lastly, here's the example from google code:

http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/docs/js/rendering.html#_intro_CSC

How do I resolve these errors and fix the double click issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was going about this the wrong way - to do the things I want to do, it's better to use the JSON Custom Search API - with documentation available here:

http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html